# Free Lexical Analyzer / Scanner Source

Tags: compiler-theory, lexical-analysis

I'm looking for a hand-written free lexer/scanner for any language, even a toy language written in a language similiar to C/C++. I am a beginner in creating languages and compiler design, I'd like to play around with the source.

For example, theres a hand written lexer on this website before the flex generated lex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser

Thanks.

Comment: Additional resources that might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the [LLVM tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl1.html#language) -- it starts by presenting a hand-written lexer for a toy language called Kaleidoscope, first as a "literate programming" exercise with good textual explanations of each bit; it continues by building a parser that builds an abstract syntax tree in the same style; then the whole thing (400 lines of hand-writted standalone C++ for lexer, parser and AST builder) is shown again as a complete .cpp source file, so you don't have to put it all together by yourself.  Following chapters show code generation, JIT, optimization, ... a truly useful little tutorial indeed!  But, you can stop with the lexer, if that's all you want to understand for now;-).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/), which is probably the most widely used lexer on the planet.

Comment: Looking for hand-written lexers.

Comment: Oh, missed that bit.  Ummmm... good luck, I guess.  Is this a homework-related question?  I can't easily think of a reason anyone would write a lexer by hand other than they were taking a compiler construction course and it was an assignment.  Come to think of it, that sort of assignment would come about right now in the semester.

Comment: @Tim, don't you just *hate* it when people repeat themselves like that (as if we couldn't understand).

Answer (score 0):

[Lex and Yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/) are the "classic" tools used for the purpose of building languages and compilers.

Comment: Looking for hand-written lexers